# jinja 2 удалить тест из значения переменной

Tags: ansible, jinja2

есть переменная в ansible
a: text1@ip,text2@ip

нужно как то в шаблоне jinja2 удалить из списка text1@ip, пробовал удалять через replace но не вышло, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте просто заменить необходимую часть строки по регулярке:

`- lineinfile:
    path: your-file
    regexp: 'text1@ip'
    line: ''
    state: present`

отформатировать можно под себя.